# Is there an event to see if an error has been fired?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

*I’m just trying to know how, so I can make my discord.js bot detect errors and send it to me.*

Comment: You could technically wrap your whole code with a try catch block but that's prob not optimal, all of the messages that are async you can call `.catch(console.error)` incase there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the code module where you would like to handle this error.
Seems that you're looking to use javascript's `try...catch` code block syntax. It goes like this:

```
"use strict";

try {

  // Your buggy code:
  let result = 2 + "2";

} catch (e) {

  // Your instructions if an <e> error occurs
  console.log(e);

}
```

I cannot know what you mean by

> [...] "errors and send it to me."

How would you like the client to send this errors to you? Please try being more specific next time. I hope `console.log` does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error from the promise returned by an action, e.g.

```
message.channel.send('Hello').catch(e => {
  // do error handling here
  console.log(e)
})
```